# Is it possible to manually select features when scaffolding using vite like the vue/cli does?

Tags: vuejs3, scaffolding, vite

Like in Vue CLI - I would like to have a way to select features manually when scaffolding with vite. Is that Possible.

I scanned through the vite documentation and couldn't find anything like that.

[Vue CLI asking if I want to manually select Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZkCd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the official command to scaffold a Vite project (`npm init vite`) uses  [`@vitejs/create-vite`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/create-vite), which does not prompt for individual features (unlike Vue CLI).

It only prompts for:

- [project name](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/085a621/packages/create-vite/index.js#L144)
- [overwrite existing directory](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/085a621/packages/create-vite/index.js#L153)
- [package name](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/085a621/packages/create-vite/index.js#L171)
- [framework](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/085a621/packages/create-vite/index.js#L182) (e.g., Vue, Svelte, etc.)
- [variant](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/085a621/packages/create-vite/index.js#L196) (e.g., Vue with Vanilla JavaScript, Vue with TypeScript)